# Using openpyxl to swap rows

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a spread sheet of objects, a new value for these objects is generated every day and saved in a new cell along side the old ones.

I want to create a new sheet and order my objects by the size of the value given that day.

I can write the code to sort according to the size of the values, i'm just a little confused as to how i would move the associated row along with the ordered values? Maybe create a list of lists, where each sub list contains data for each row. Then sort by the element corresponding to the latest value. Sounds a bit convoluted anyone have a better idea ? here's a sample of the data https://github.com/mrsmn/coinmarketcap-api/files/71682/new_values2.xlsx

Thanks

Comment: I'd be tempted to let Excel do the sorting and just add the relevant criteria to the file. See `openpyxl.worksheet.filters.py` and the associated tests for how to do this. Otherwise you probably need to look at sorting in Python using a sort function.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe create a list of lists, where each sub list contains data for each row. Then sort by the element corresponding to the latest

Instead of bothering with all that, use a dataframe. Sort it, and re-save the excel file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(input_excel_path, sheetname=sheet_name)
df.sort(column_name_to_sort_by, inplace=True, ascending=False) # the default for 'ascending' is True
df.to_excel(output_excel_path)
```

Comment: This kind of s assumes that the OP knows a) what Pandas is and has it installed. As such it's not the best answer to the question.